# adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth doesn't properly work

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, uilabel

I'm developing an app for iOS > 5.0 and using Xcode 4.6.2
To explain  my problem, I've a `UIScrollView` which contains only a bunch of `UILabel`. The text that i'm going to display in these `UILabel`s are dynamic but, `UILabel`'s frame is constant, so if current text doesn't fit in the frame width, I need to scale my font size down. So, i've found `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property of `UILabel`.

Here is the explanation I took directly from `UILabel` class reference.

> A Boolean value indicating whether the font size should be reduced in order to fit the title string into the label’s bounding rectangle.

Yeap, I thought that's what i exactly looking for since the text that i'm going to display in `UILabel` is always one line. **So i'm aware of this property should be used with `numberOfLines` property to set 1.**

Here is my code to make this happen.

```
for (NSString *currentImage in self.imagesNames)
{
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageNumber*resultTypeImageWidth, 10, 75, 35)];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"GothamRounded-Bold" size:25]];
    [lbl setNumberOfLines:1];
    [lbl setText:currentImage];
    [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:0.07 saturation:1 brightness:0.49 alpha:1.0]];
    [lbl adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    imageNumber++;
    [self.resultTypeScrollView addSubview:lbl];
}
```

`imageNumber` is a **int** that i'm using to place this `UILabel`s in appropriate place in my `UIScrollView` which is name `resultTypeScrollView`. `resultTypeImageWidth` is a constant i've defined and set 100 to give some space between `UILabel`s.

So, my problem is if the text doesn't fit in the label's frame, it gets truncated. I expected that if text doesn't fit the frame, font size will scale down to fit it. At least, that's what i understand from `UILabel` [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html). Apparently, i'm missing something, but what ?

So far,

1. As i'm using custom font, I suspect that using custom font would be a problem. So, I changed to one of the system font, it has no effect.
2. I tried to set `NSLineBreakMode`to  `NSLineBreakByClipping` to prevent text getting truncated. After that, text doesn't get truncated but, some characters are missing which got truncated before.
3. I've used also `minimumScaleFactor` to set different values to see if it has any effect, but, no effects at all.

Comment: this should just work without changing many defaults.  one thing i notice is your code doesn't set adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth, it only gets it.  setting would look like this lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

Comment: @danh, that was the issue, i don't know how i missed it, add your comment as answer, i'll accept it, thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should just work without changing many defaults. The posted code doesn't set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, it only gets it. Setting would look like this:

```
lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```